# Role to Grant Update Access on All tables in a database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want create a role in SQL server 2008, which will allows specific group of users to have update permissions on all the tables in a specific database.
I tried using tha management studio GUI, but i have so many tables in that and its tough to select on by one and assign update access.
Could some please tell me a way to write the script or a sample script that will make my life easier.
Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: UPDATE? or INSERT and DELETE too?

Comment: @gbn.. Yes you are right...Update insert and delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [db_datawriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175039%28SQL.90%29.aspx) role for "write on all tables"

Comment: @gbn...is there a way we can customize that role to user specific?   i mean giving a different name to that role?

Comment: @S.. : sorry, not sure. This is a "special" role. You could try GRANT INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON schema::dbo TO MyRole http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want use your own rolename, you can grant it the equivalent permissions to db_datawriter and db_datareader:

```
    GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO MyRole 
    GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO MyRole 
    GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO MyRole 
    GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO MyRole 
    GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO MyRole
```